# How do I use UPX with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, compression, pyinstaller

How do I use UPX  with pyinstaller?

I am following the docs.

I have downloaded UPX.

My file looks like:

```
import csv
import selenium
import pandas

print('Hello')
```

I then run:

```
pyinstaller -F --upx-dir C:\Users\DD\Downloads\upx394w\upx394w\123\upx308w\upx.exe zz.spec
```

This does not affect the size of the file.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['zz.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\DA\\13\\14'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='zz',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The UPX directory, not UPX executable needs to be specified:

e.g.:

`pyinstaller myfile.py --upx-dir=..\upx391w -y --onefile`

Comment: This works, though I'm getting "api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll: CantPackException: can't pack new-exe".  I've read somewhere that 64 bit support windows is still experimental maybe that is why

Comment: maybe you are experiencing this issue? what is your pyinstaller version?
 https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1565

Comment: I got it working.  It reduced the size by 700kbs haha, so not a great deal but it worked.

Comment: Actually I re-tested just now, and its not even doing any upx.  Bizzare.

Comment: Works today.  I got a one dir that went from 70mb to 20mb that's as good as 7zip but you can run the exe.  pyinstaller myfile.py --upx-dir=C:\upx394w -y --onedir --clean. I added --clean to it so it would stop getting old build.  --noupx to test difference.

Comment: @user9062171, how did you figure out which directory to specify for upx?  Also, how did you tell if upx was working?  I see: `85 INFO: UPX is available.`, but I don't know how to tell if UPX is actually used...

Comment: Just compare the size of executable with and without upx

Comment: there is no difference in the size whether or not I use the --upx-dir option.  That's why I'm confused.

Comment: that probably means you have achieved minimum entropy of information

Comment: Maybe.  It is confusing because the output of Pyinstaller is the same whether I specify --no-upx, --upx-dir, or no specification at all, thus giving me no indication whether or not upx is functioning.

Comment: Just for benefits of newbies like me, you have to separately download UPX from github and unzip it somewhere on your system, then write that folder path (absolute or relative) after`--upxdir=`. Get the latest UPX from https://github.com/upx/upx/releases .

Comment: Thank you sir for this code, Now I able to create a file but it doesn't have any extension just simple **Hello** file is there How I can run this file

Answer (score 3):

Adding a new answer, since it appears that PyInstaller is more helpful now (in September 2019) than the current answer and comments suggest.

I see the output `934 INFO: UPX is available.` early in the build if UPX is working.

Additionally, I can see many lines of output where PyInstaller is calling upx.

I didn't specify `--upx-dir`, but did have `upx.exe` available in my `$PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

##### Just install `upx`

```
sudo apt install upx
```

*Pyinstaller searches for `upx`* ***by default*** unless you specify the flag [--noupx](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-upx).

The above installation will automatically add `upx` to the `$PATH` variable and then you do not need to specify `--upx-dir` flag.

Other way is to download the zip file from [upx's repo](https://upx.github.io/) and use `--upx-dir` flag.
Refer to [@denfromufa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821887/10204932)'s answer.

> For windows, the steps might differ.

Comment: hein? you just told a window user to use apt...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to GlennS' comment: exact this behaviour is stated in the `pyinstaller` documentation. so this is not an undocumented accidental benefit in this regard.
See https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html#using-upx

Answer (score 1):

Check that your script name is correctly spelled. In my case I received the mentioned error because I was using pyinstaller.exe -F .\my_script.py but my script name was my-script.py (notice the '-' vs '_').

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. –

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with UPX as it might not be downloaded so the first step you should do is download UPX over here[UPX official](https://github.com/upx/upx/releases/)

then once downloaded extract it to a specific folder. There you will find the .exe file so now in the same directory just open cmd and run the command of pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py
```

I hope this works now.